# (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse() throwing The operation has timed out

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, httpwebrequest, system.net.webexception

I am trying to post my data using HTTPWebRequest to third party WebAPI. My data gets posted successfully, however in my error log I see a log saying The operation has timed out in (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse().

I am unable to find out why though my data is posted successfully. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your request is sent to server successfully but you fail to get response. If it always happens, maybe the WebAPI takes a lot of time to deal with the request before sending response so that your HttpWebRequest doesn't wait anymore. Try setting `HttpWebRequest.Timeout` a large value.

Comment: Thanks skyoxZ...is it fine to set timeout value as Timeout.Infinite, is it recommended?

Comment: @pallavi Infinite is not recommended. See how much time it takes to get response and set `Timeout` to a value that is large enough to get response most of the time.